# Searching for files from user input

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write part of a batch file that will ask the user for a file name and then search for that file. I have looked around for ages but I can't find any examples of where searching is done from user input.

If the users input is stored in a variable using `set /p myVar = (users input)` is it not then possible to do a command such as: `dir %myVar%`

If not then what is the correct way to search based on user input?

Comment: Sure that is possible. What do you want to do with the file after you find it?

Comment: After the file has been found i just want to copy it to another location, possibly more but just basic file copying, deleting editing etc.

Comment: @Phill use `dir *%myvar%*` or more usefully `for %%f in (*%myvar%*) do ( echo %%f )` to do something for each file found.

Comment: Show us your code and tell us where you are having a problem.

Comment: what significance do the *'s have, do they act as wildcards searching for anything with that name?

Comment: The only code I have currently is: `set /p input = enter a file name......dir /b %input%

Comment: Are you expecting the user will only enter a file name and you want to search through subfolders looking for it?

Comment: Yes its going to be specifically for searching for the file they specify, (they wont be inputting any other data) and yes I would like it to then search the computer for that file. the file is likely to be within a normal place users\documents etc but If it could look everywhere it would be better. or would it?

Comment: @aphoria do you have an example I could try?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler the dir *%myVar%* you suggested doesn't seem to work, whatever input i specify it always seems to show the same directory....

Comment: @Phill well yeah, dir only looks in the directory you are in. And the asterisks are wildcard parameters so you type "report" and it finds "report.txt", "my report.doc", "report of finances.xls", etc. To search all subdirectories, try `dir c:\*%MyVar%* /S` but note that's only on drive C, not all drives.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler OK thanks, so dir c:\ *%myVar%* found the test file i created (after a long long search obviously) so to wrap this is an if statement I would want to say IF EXIST *%myVar%* (del or copy or whatever) ELSE (echo file not found.) or would I still need to include the dir from above?

Comment: @Phill You're reaching at the limits of batch files, have you considered PowerShell? I've added an answer with a possible script. (Also, please add these kind of conditions of things you need in your original questions, rather than deep in comment threads, it would save everyone a lot of back and forth and heading down dead ends).

Answer (score 1):

Batch file to search a drive, subfolders, do something for each file found, and have a way of telling if nothing was found:

(edit: missed a /s out)

```
@echo off

set /P MyVar="Search for:"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in (`dir /b /s c:\*%MyVar%*`) do (
    set _foundstuff=yes
    echo copy "%%f" "c:\somewhere\"
)

if "%_foundstuff%"=="yes" goto fin

rem nothing found code goes here
echo "nothing found"

:fin
```